# How to raise exception if a background subprocess fails?

Tags: python, subprocess

In my python script I want to run some background subprocesses. I want python not to wait for the subprocess to finish, BUT raise an exception if the subprocess fails.

I believe the typical way to run background processes is this:

```
subprocess.Popen("script.sh")
# Move on doing something else
```

But this ignores if `script.sh` exits unsuccessfullly.

I know I can also do this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("script.sh")
process.communicate()
if process.returncode:
    raise Exception
# Move on doing something else
```

But this waits for the process to finish, which I don't want.

For context, I expect `script.sh` to take ~3 seconds to run and to only fail in the worst case scenario (i.e. the failure of `script.sh` is not part of my program's logic, but indicates some actual, unrecoverable error). 99% of the time the user shouldn't even know that `script.sh` is running; but in the 1% case, it's better if python simply crashes than continue running and ignore the error.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with two ideas. Which you prefer depends on your main thread implementation.

The first approach is to use [poll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll). This is better suited for implementations that do something else while waiting for the sub-process to finish. This approach is simple, but you will need to periodically check the status of the sub-process in the main thread.

```py
import subprocess
import time


class PollingWorker:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(args)

    @property
    def return_code(self):
        return self.process.poll()


def run_polling():
    worker = PollingWorker("script.sh")

    # Move on doing something else
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

        # But you need to check return_code periodically.
        if worker.return_code:
            print("ERROR:", worker.args)
            return
```

The second approach is to use threads. This approach allows you to wait for the sub-process to finish without blocking the main thread by executing the sub-process in a sub-thread. Note that this approach eliminates periodic checks, but makes error handling a bit more complicated.

```py
import _thread
import subprocess
import threading
import time


class ThreadWorker:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._run_in_thread, args=(args,))
        self.thread.start()

    def _run_in_thread(self, args):
        try:
            subprocess.run(args, check=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print("ERROR:", args, e)
            # Note that this method is executed in sub thread.
            # That is, raising an exception here will not terminate main thread.
            # Instead, following raises KeyboardInterrupt in main thread.
            _thread.interrupt_main()


def run_thread():
    # You need to keep worker instances to avoid garbage collection.
    worker = ThreadWorker("script.sh")

    # Move on doing something else
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

        # This case, you have nothing to take care of.
```

Comment: I appreciate the very detailed comments.